# React-native-track-player NPM install bug with react@17.0.1

Tags: react-native, react-native-track-player

I tried installing this module with npm, but recieved a bug which I cannot understand.

I have tried to install *multiple* versions of the package, including the **dev-version** and none has yielded any good results.

***I am Wondering wether I have to downgrade my react install or if there might be any other solutions?***

I cannot follow the error message I recieved, and I get confused about what is really the issue. I did think it might be the servers that were down, but when this keeps happening, I do not know what to do.

Thanks in advance!
[image: Error_log from trying to install module]